# How to name the ticks in a python matplotlib boxplot

Tags: python, matplotlib

Python [matplotlib](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/) has a [boxplot command](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.boxplot).

Normally, all the parts of the graph are numerically ticked. How can I change the ticks to names instead of positions?

For illustration, I mean the Mon Tue Wed labels like in this boxplot:

[image]

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Use the second argument of `xticks` to set the labels:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = [[np.random.rand(100)] for i in range(3)]
plt.boxplot(data)
plt.xticks([1, 2, 3], ['mon', 'tue', 'wed'])
```

edited to remove `pylab` bc *[`pylab` is a convenience module that bulk imports `matplotlib.pyplot` (for plotting) and `numpy` (for mathematics and working with arrays) in a single name space. Although many examples use `pylab`, **it is no longer recommended**.](http://matplotlib.org/faq/usage_faq.html#matplotlib-pyplot-and-pylab-how-are-they-related)*

Answer (score 13):

ars has the right, and succinct answer. I'll add that when learning how to use matplotlib, I found the [thumbnail gallery](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/gallery.html#) to be really useful for finding relevant code and examples.
For your case, I submitted [this boxplot example](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/examples/pylab_examples/boxplot_demo2.html) that shows you other functionality that could be useful (like rotating the tick mark text, adding upper Y-axis tick marks and labels, adding color to the boxes, etc.)

[image]

Comment: +1. Josh, that's a pretty complete reference sample -- thanks!